# Count all data even with zero/0 value

Tags: oracle

I have data like this

> ```
> product  location
> snack    america
> snack    brazil
> biscuit  america
> biscuit  china
> biscuit  japan
> soda     brazil
> soda     japan
> soda     india
> ```

what I want is like below, however I can do it differently using pivot, but is is possible to have the data like this?

> ```
> location product count
> america  snack   1 
> america  biscuit 1
> america  soda    0
> brazil   snack   1 
> brazil   biscuit 0
> brazil   soda    1
> japan    snack   0 
> japan    biscuit 1
> japan    soda    1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

We can generate a "calendar" table of all product/location combinations, via a cross join:

```sql
SELECT
    loc.location,
    prod.product,
    CASE WHEN t.location IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT location FROM yourTable) loc
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM yourTable) prod
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.location = loc.location AND
       t.product = prod.product
ORDER BY
    loc.location,
    prod.product;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: it's a good thing, but it took much longer than what I think

Comment: @DedeSoetopo The cross join to generate all combinations is largely probably the performance killer.  Consider maintaining separate tables of locations and products for best performance here.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate our concern, the result table that you are asking could be generated but specify your concern in a detail manner